# Workshop - not producing anything at all

Tags: prison-architect

So I was doing a grant - producing 30 license plates. I have qualified prisoners who passed the workshop safety test and they go to the workshop during every work time.

The problem I'm having is that they are not making any license plates nor are they making anything at all. They are just hanging around in the workshop. There're piles of woods and other stuff in the workshop so I doubt it's because of lack of materials.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the license plate machines? Wood would be for if you have prisoners trained in advanced workshop training, which if you are just starting would be highly unlikely.

Comment: @Ramirez what is the license plate machine called in game? I only see 3 required objects for workshop.

Comment: you require the Workshop Saw and the Workshop Press, you also require a table to store them before they are exported.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your workshop. It's either 1) you don't have the right tools (you need a press for license plates), or your tables don't have the right space around them. I never put anything but tables next to the walls, and all the tools in the middle of the room.

Comment: @TimS. I think I do have the right tools. However as Ramirez suggested above, it could be that the prisoners have not gone thru the advanced workshop training yet. So im going to check tonight when i get back home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have:

- Workshop presses (to stamp the plates)
- Workshop saws (to cut the metal)
- Generic tables (to store the materials and completed license plates)
- Workshop safety courses, that prisoners are enrolled, and you have someone teaching it

If you have a bunch of wood in the shop, it may be clogging up the room, preventing them from making license plates. Metal is used to make license plates; wood is used to make bed frames. This would especially be the case if you don't have a carpentry class, so no one knows what to do with the wood. Selling or trashing the wood might be a good idea, so metal can be brought in to make license plates.